# How to run separate loops on set of consecutive rows in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I need to run independent loops on different sets of rows depending on value of a column, for e.g. loop for column value "Monday" which is repeated from row 1 to n then "Tuesday" from n+1 to ~18, these loops need to run consecutively one after another. Example:

[image: Example as below]

Comment: Please provide additional information like what code did you execute? Did it fail with an error or expectation was not met?

Comment: select case may help, `select case left(range(""),3)`  what have you tried?

Comment: Why do you need to use consecutive loops for this? Also you aren't doing yourself any favours by keeping your dates in a non recognised excel format

Comment: Forgot to mention I need this in VBA and I am starter level. This is 3rd party excel sheet output so I can't choose the formatting. Ultimate aim is to find clashing times on each day, up until now I have been able to loop through and find clashing times on all days included, that is not of a much help. Therefore, need to run loop individually for Monday then move on to loop Tuesday and so on...

Comment: Loop for picking cell to compare For rwIndex = 1 To 100    
        For colIndex = 3 To 25 loop inside to compare with all cells in the sheet For rwIndex_ = 1 To 100
                    For colIndex_ = 3 To 25 then highlight the same times - Right(Sheets("Staff Schedule").Cells(rwIndex, colIndex).Value, 5) and Right(Sheets("Staff Schedule").Cells(rwIndex_, colIndex_).Value, 5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to check whether you have duplicate times for a given day.  In total you'll have 3 nested loops: the first to iterate through all the rows in the worksheet, the next to iterate through all the rows of a given day and the last to iterate through the column entries.

It appears that you're not interested in the initial string in each cell (for example 'Res01', 'Res02', etc) but just want to know whether there are identical times for a given day and to highlight both cells of that duplicate.

Also since you only want duplicates within a given day, the dictionary is cleared out when processing is started for that day.  The key of the dictionary is the time string and the value is the address of the cell.  For each cell the macro checks whether that time is already in the dictionary.  If it is then that's a duplicate and both the original cell and the current cell background colors are changed.  If not then the key/value pair is stored and processing continues.

I decided to change the color of background (green/blue) showing duplicates for consecutive days just to make it easier to see the differences.

```
Option Explicit

Sub HighliteDiffs()
  Dim sht As Worksheet
  Set sht = Worksheets("Staff Schedule")

  Dim r As Integer, c As Integer, clr As Integer: clr = 4
  Dim curDay As String, val As String, addr As String

  Dim dict As Object
  Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

  Dim rng As Range

  With sht
    Dim lastRow As Integer, lastCol As Integer
    lastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    r = 2
    Do While r <= lastRow
      If clr = 4 Then
        clr = 5
      Else
        clr = 4
      End If
      dict.RemoveAll
      curDay = Left(Cells(r, "A").Value, 11)
      Do While curDay = Left(Cells(r, "A").Value, 11)
        lastCol = .Cells(r, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        For c = 3 To lastCol
          val = Right(.Cells(r, c).Value, 5)
          If dict.Exists(val) Then
            addr = dict(val)
            Set rng = .Cells(Range(addr).Row, Range(addr).Column)
            rng.Interior.ColorIndex = clr
            .Cells(r, c).Interior.ColorIndex = clr
          Else
            dict(val) = .Cells(r, c).Address
          End If
        Next
        r = r + 1
      Loop
    Loop
  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: That is some great looking code! The only issue is that my excel does not look exactly as I posted earlier. The first cell with date is always E4 not A1 and with times G4 not C1. In the code I changed the column from A to E and started the column loop from 7 rather than 3. It still misses some duplicates in the process?

Comment: Works for the data set I used (based on what you posted).  Only the time is stored as a key - so if, say, "08:45" is in the dictionary then any other entries with this time should get colored as a duplicate.  You could have trailing spaces or something that makes the time strings different from each other.  You'll have to debug to see why duplicates are being missed.  You can 'step into' the code and hit F8 to execute each line by line to see what going on.

Comment: It is working now. Next I need to skip some rows depending on text in column C, hopefully should be able insert code. Thank you

Comment: If what I've posted is the 'solution' you should indicate it as such.  This does a couple of things: prioritizes the post for web searches (more visible to others and possibly helps them too), marks it as complete so people that answer questions know that it's been resolved, and provides up-votes to posters - which will be good for you as well given that people who answer are more likely to review your future questions.

Comment: Where do I indicate as this being "solution"?

Comment: Click the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, please let me know if there is anything I could do, is there any book or website you would recommend for learning Excel VBA?

Comment: You could start with this ([link](http://www.jlathamsite.com/teach/vba/programminginexcelvba_anintroduction.pdf)).  VBA is huge, so once you've got an handle on the basics, it's really a matter of googling to get what you're after.